# Cannot convert value of type '[(Measurement, [MeasurementValue])?]' to closure result type '(Measurement, [MeasurementValue])?'

Tags: swift3

```
class func measurementsFromMeasurementsDB(_ measurementsDB: [CIMeasurement]) -> [(Measurement, [MeasurementValue])] {

    var measurements: [(Measurement, [MeasurementValue])?] = measurementsDB.map {return measurementsFromMeasurementsDB([($0)])}

    measurements = measurements.filter {$0 != nil}
    return measurements.map {return $0!}
}
```

Comment: Show the declaration of measurementsFromMeasurementsDB

Comment: The error message says an optional tuple `(Measurement, [MeasurementValue])?` is expected but an array `[(Measurement, [MeasurementValue])?] ` is passed. Basically do not annotate types the compiler can infer.

Comment: can you give me any solution?

Comment: First of all answer Nirav's question, then remove the type annotation. What happens?